# Google Cloud DNS intermittently dropping

Tags: google-cloud-dns

Situation:

- Had registered domain via G Suite and domain synthetic records set up for gmail  under another (Google) account.
- Transferred the domain to a different (Google) account - gmail still working fine.
- Enabled Google Cloud services for the account.
- Set up a Compute Engine with fixed IP address.
- Set up new Zone for the domain and Cloud DNS settings.

  - Reset the domain DNS to the Cloud DNS servers
  - Create MX records according to instructions to reinstate gmail
  - Created A record for root domain
  - Created CNAME record for WWW subdomain

At this point, gmail seems to be working fine.

However, resolution for the root domain and subdomain is intermittent - it will be up for a few minutes, then drop for a few minutes.

When its alive, I can ping the root domain.  I can't ping the www subdomain at all.

The domain is 'lifetreelaw.com'

Here are the dig outputs for each:

lifetreelaw.com:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-3ubuntu5.3-Ubuntu <<>> lifetreelaw.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 25514
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;lifetreelaw.com.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
lifetreelaw.com.    325 IN  A   34.66.70.41

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Fri May 10 13:33:51 MDT 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 60
```

www.lifetreelaw.com:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-3ubuntu5.3-Ubuntu <<>> www.lifetreelaw.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 36100
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.lifetreelaw.com.       IN  A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Fri May 10 13:33:40 MDT 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 48
```

For the www subroute, dig is showing an 'A' record, not the CNAME record.  I haven't set that -- is there something in the G Suite/gmail setup that would have set that?  That is hanging around?

**Followup**

I removed the www CNAME record.  This is the dig output, now:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-3ubuntu5.3-Ubuntu <<>> www.lifetree.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 60309
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.lifetree.com.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.lifetree.com.   4160    IN  A   208.91.197.128

;; Query time: 4 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Fri May 10 13:50:14 MDT 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 61
```

It's still returning an A record, and resolving to a different IP.

**Followup 2**

Ok, after a period of time, the 'www' sub is not returning an 'A' record, anymore.  But it's not returning a 'CNAME' record, either, even though I have it set.

Maybe I just need to wait it out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, waiting it out was part of the answer -- I'm just not used to a DNS name change taking so long to propagate and settle down.

The other part of the answer seemed to be flushing the DNS cache at this site:

https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/cache

And everything seemed to straighten out.